# Advanced search functionality in Doxygen?

Tags: php, search, documentation, doxygen, phpdoc

I'm researching different solutions to generate documentation based on phpdoc, Doxygen looks awesome but the search has been severely limited so far.

Example, I search for the string "session" and it gives me 2 results:

- sessionExists Lib_Session
- sessionMatchesIp Lib_Session

The same class also has a method called getSession, which I can't seem to find. Not only that but the class itself has "Session" right there in the name, yet it's not in the search results.

Is there any way Doxygen could actually search for these methods / classes, or is it designed to be limited in functionality?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer my own question, I found out you get more thorough search results when switching to [Server Side Searching](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/searching.html). Of course the trade-of is that you have additional requirements on top of "a browser", but I'm personally ok with that.